# AI for trading card game

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm making a trading card game such as Yu-gi-oh using c++ and qt. I finished the basic functions of the game such as : drawing , attacking , summoning etc.. .However I'm really stumped in the AI part since its my first time making one and i need some advice to get started.

I've already done some research on the subject but the amount of results is so confusing that i don't know what to use for my problem.

Is there any algorithms i should know of , or some techniques concerning AI in general ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you should have a baseline. Probably you can use a statistical approach. If you have acces to data about the game, you can turn that to dataset. For example (since I used to play), Record each action within each player's turn (Setting how many monster cards face-up/face-down, how many magic/trap cards, Life Points by end of turn for both players). This way, you make a probabilistic model (A monster card is chosen given certain conditions are met).

A more sophisticated model could incorporate Reinforcement Learning to make the model figure out what actions are suppose to be taken. Again this requires gaming data.

The above approach, however, don't take to acount the textual info of each card. So maybe for your first model, you should limit the game to only normal monsters with defend or attack positions. However, games likes DOTA 2 also have many options and equips that have various effects and an AI model made by OpenAI was able to even beat top players in 1-on-1 play, they used Reinforcement Learning. You can search more about that as well.